# Github Extension not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, github

Alright, so the game Agar.io is where you eat cells and you are a cell. I was on Github today, and found a repository that had an open source Skin Changer.

The repo is: https://github.com/SebyakinAndrei/Agar.io-Free-Skin

So basically at the top this asks users for skin name and skin URL. I want to pull that and change the code so that instead of showing that, it will be chosen already. Now the issue is getting the code to work.

There are two parts to the program, one which is called addon.js and another one that is called Free.Skins.user.js. Both of those are on the repo. The user.js just tells tampermonkey to look at the code on the addon.js. The issue I am having is that I download the addon.js and try to upload to my server and then try to get the user.js to load it up. I do everything correctly, the JavaScript is also up on the host and still it won't load the addon.js. I didn't modify anything.

I also tried uploading it myself to Github on my own repository, it still didn't work.

My Repo: https://github.com/makanenzo10/abs0rb_skins

I also tried uploading the script to rawgit.com. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Have you tried reaching out to the developer?

Comment: I'll try to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Nevermind I got it to work. I had to upload it to rawgit.com using the development mode :/